# Ошибка в реквесте Postman - deserialization

Tags: c#, rest

Ошибка в реквесте Postman - deserialization.

Такое в теле запроса POSTMAN:

```
{
    "roles":  
        [
            {
                "role_id": "TEST1",
                "role_name": "Для тестов"
            },
            {
                "role_id": "TEST3",
                "role_name": "Для тестов
            }
        ]
}
```

Модель -

```
public class Role 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "role_id")]
    public string role_id { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "role_name")]
    public string role_name { get; set; }

    
}
```

Контроллер метод

```
[HttpPost("[action]/")]
public ActionResult<UserReply> SetRoleMessage(string message_text, List<Role> roles)
{
    Log("POST api/User/SetRoleMessage" + token + "\n" + message_text + "\n" + JSONutils.json_to_string(roles), Logger.LogLevel.Request);

    UserReply result;

    using (DatabaseAuth db = new DatabaseAuth())
    {
        result = db.SetRoleMessage(message_text, roles, token);
    }

    if (result != null)
    {
        Log(result.jsonString(), Logger.LogLevel.Reply);

        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        Response.StatusCode = 500;

        result = new UserReply(Constants.ERROR_UNKNOWN, Constants.ERROR_UNKNOWN_MSG);
        Log(result.jsonString(), Logger.LogLevel.Error);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Далее Постман с ошибкой -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу помощи, заранее спасибо

Comment: List в класс закиньте

Comment: Та это вариант я знаю, хочется список передавать

Answer (score 1):

Я отправляю объект со свойством «роли», который представляет собой массив. Но  контроллер ожидает, что я отправлю массив.
Изменить нужно так реквест:

```
[
    {
        "role_id": "TEST1",
        "role_name": "Для тестов"
    },
    {
        "role_id": "TEST3",
        "role_name": "Для тестов"
    }
]
```